# Having trouble implementing Braintree payment for Android using Firebase as backend

Tags: android, firebase, braintree

I get this output on firebase: "Cannot determine payment method"

Note: I don't have too much knowledge on JavaScript and Firebase functions and can't get this to work.

I have been following Braintree's guide to setting up the payment method. This is the flow of events:

> Step 1
>   Your front-end requests a client token from your server and initializes the client SDK.
>
> Step 2
>   Your server generates and sends a client token back to your client using the server SDK.
>
> Step 3
>   The customer submits payment information, the client SDK communicates that information to Braintree and returns a payment method nonce.
>
> Step 4
>   Your front-end sends the payment method nonce to your server.
>
> Step 5
>   Your server code receives the payment method nonce and then uses the server SDK to create a transaction.

So far I've been stuck at step 5. The nonce gets posted to my Firebase database in the following format:

```
-nonce
   -LsHNQLklFEX48oiSt1H:"tokencc_bc_vbmypn_dvn4gy_xy47fw_th6vv9_bq6"
   -LsHn2hilKlmVeT1g1Ow: tokencc_bf_8qrjsk_j7bg44_p8kk88_qz7vn2_vk6"
```

How would i go about step 5?

Functions code:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const app = express(); 
const braintree = require('braintree');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

var clientToken;
var nonceFromTheClient;
var transaction;

var gateway = braintree.connect({
                        environment: braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
                        merchantId:"",
                        publicKey: "",
                        privateKey: ""
});

exports.createToken = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (err, response) {
    if (err){
        console.log('inside error',err);    
    } else {
        clientToken = response.clientToken;
    }
});
response.send(clientToken);
});

exports.createTransaction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

app.post("/nonce", function (req, res) {
    nonceFromTheClient = req.body.payment_method_nonce;
    console.log("nonce" + nonceFromTheClient)
});

gateway.transaction.sale({amount: '10.00', paymentMethodNonce: nonceFromTheClient, options: {submitForSettlement: true}}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    if (result.success) {
        console.log('Transaction status: ' + result.transaction.status);
    } else {
        console.error(result.message);
    }
});
res.send(transaction);
});
```

Activity code:

```
if (cardPayment.isChecked) {
            val client = AsyncHttpClient()
            client.get(
                "https://.../createToken",
                object : TextHttpResponseHandler() {
                    override fun onFailure(
                        statusCode: Int,
                        headers: Array<out Header>?,
                        responseString: String?,
                        throwable: Throwable?
                    ) {

                    }

                    override fun onSuccess(
                        statusCode: Int,
                        headers: Array<Header>,
                        clientToken: String
                    ) {
                        mClientToken = clientToken

                        onBraintreeSubmit(it)
                    }
                })
        }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && data != null) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val result =
                data.getParcelableExtra<DropInResult>(DropInResult.EXTRA_DROP_IN_RESULT)
            val nonce = result.paymentMethodNonce?.nonce
            if (nonce != null) {
                FirebaseShoppingCartDatabase.postNonceToDatabase(nonce)
                val client = AsyncHttpClient()

                client.get(
                    "https://..../createTransaction",
                    object : TextHttpResponseHandler() {
                        override fun onFailure(
                            statusCode: Int,
                            headers: Array<out Header>?,
                            responseString: String?,
                            throwable: Throwable?
                        ) {

                        }

                        override fun onSuccess(
                            statusCode: Int,
                            headers: Array<Header>,
                            clientToken: String
                        ) {

                        }
                    })
            }

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

        } else {
            // handle errors here, an exception may be available in
            val error = data.getSerializableExtra(DropInActivity.EXTRA_ERROR) as Exception
            System.out.println("eroare " + error)
        }
    }
}

fun onBraintreeSubmit(v: View) {
    val dropInRequest = DropInRequest()
        .clientToken(mClientToken)
    dropInRequest
        .disablePayPal()
    startActivityForResult(dropInRequest.getIntent(context), REQUEST_CODE)
}
}
```

Comment: Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. Please reach out to our [support team](https://help.braintreepayments.com/) with your [merchant ID](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/important-gateway-credentials#merchant-id) so we can take a look at our server log for the cause of this error. That said, as long as you are passing the nonce to your server correctly, you should be able to create a transaction with it.

Comment: Actually I got it to work. I was passing the nonce incorrectly to the server. Thanks:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work. I was passing the nonce to the server incorrectly. (using a different URL)